# Angular BrowserAnimationsModule Lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-animations

I imported BrowserAnimationsModule in my app.module but, when I have compiled my project, my main.js file has grown a lot.

Is there a way to lazy load BrowserAnimationsModule?

I tried to import it in app.component.js in this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
import('src/libs/ng-uikit-pro/pro/alerts/toast/toast.module').then(m => m.ToastModule);
}
```

or in this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
const module = await import('@angular/platform-browser/animations');
const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(module.BrowserAnimationsModule);
const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
}
```

but components that use Angular animations don't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per [#24717](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24717), `BrowserAnimationsModule` should never be lazyloaded.